# Exchange-online run PS script Set-UnifiedGroup from application

Tags: azure, exchange-server, exchange-online

i need run script using powershel , witch modyfy domain for aad email group.
Set-UnifiedGroup

I managed to achive it from the console after granting the Exchange Administrator role. But I need to use this script in the application, and MFA is required for the Exchange Administrator role.
I was thinking about registering the application and logging in to PS using secret , but I don't really know what type of application permissions I need to give to be able to change the domain of the aad group email address.
And is it feasible this way.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Create an **Azure AD application and grant API permission** like below:

[image]

Upload the **`.cer`** certificate in Certificates and secrets blade:

[image]

Make sure the **`.pfx`** certificate is stored in the local machine where you are executing the script:

[image]

Now assign **Exchange Administrator role** to the Azure AD service principal:

[image]

Now **connect to Exchange online** using app only authentication:

```
$tenantID = 'xxx.onmicrosoft.com'
$appID = 'ClientID'
$CertificateFilePath = 'PFXpath'
$pfxPassword = 'Password'

## Connect to Exchange Online
Connect-ExchangeOnline -CertificateFilePath $CertificateFilePath `
-CertificatePassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -String $pfxPassword -AsPlainText -Force) `
-AppID $appID `
-Organization $tenantID
```

[image]

For **sample**, I set `HiddenFromExchangeClientsEnabled` as true without any prompt:

```
Get-UnifiedGroup -Identity testrukk

Set-UnifiedGroup -identity "ID" -HiddenFromExchangeClientsEnabled:$true
```

[image]

*As I don't have any custom domain the command executed (with a warning) **successfully without any MFA/prompt**:*

```
Set-UnifiedGroup -Identity "testrukk" -EmailAddresses @{Add ="testrukk@xxx.onmicrosoft.com"}

Set-UnifiedGroup -Identity "testrukk" -PrimarySmtpAddress testrukk@xxx.onmicrosoft.com
```

[image]

**Reference:**

[App-only authentication in Exchange Online PowerShell and Security & Compliance PowerShell | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/app-only-auth-powershell-v2?view=exchange-ps#step-1-register-the-application-in-azure-ad)